# Why does console.dir('') print "no properties"?

Tags: javascript

I was under the impression that strings have properties, such as `match`. Why does `console.dir('')` claim that `''` has no properties (at least in Google Chrome)?

Comment: Same result though? (in Firefox)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `''` is a string literal, not an instance of the `String` "class". As properties like `match` are declared on `String.prototype`, you won't see them when using a string literal. If you use the `new` operator you will see what you expected:

```
var s = new String("hello");
console.dir(s);
```

Here's a screenshot from Chrome's developer tools (notice the need to expand the `prototype`, as the method you're expecting to see is declared on the prototype, not the `String` object itself):

[image]

Comment: Intriguingly, Firebug's result is rather different.

Comment: Hmm. Firebug seems to list the methods twice. Once for the object itself and again for the `prototype`. It also seems to ignore the `length` property.

Comment: I'm still somewhat unconvinced here. Why does `''.match`, `''.constructor`, etc. not print `undefined`, and yet `dir('')` does not print them?

Comment: @Randomblue - Hmm. I can only assume the runtime performs an automatic cast to the `String` object, otherwise you would have to explicitly do so every time you want to use a method of `String.prototype`. However, I could be wrong. I've just asked a question to see if anyone can clear this up once and for all! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581874/why-are-methods-of-string-prototype-available-to-string-literals

Comment: @Randomblue - And we have an answer :) it's back to the spec I'm afraid: http://es5.github.com/#x8.7.1 (see accepted answer on question for the exact extract)

Answer (score 2):

Likely for the same reason that console.dir(true) and console.dir(1234) say that once you turn down the knob pointing to the data.  It's likely the code only iterates through properties if it's an Object. Why that turndown knob is still there is unclear.

Comment: `Strings` are objects, `Arrays` are objects, for `Functions` it will list the `prototype`, very peculiar. Perhaps just some `console.dir` magic? `console.log` is pretty magic too (like on DOMElements). The Firefox spec is very unhelpful.

Comment: Hmmm .. `"" instanceof String` is `false` .. WHY!? `typeof ""` returns `"string"` though. I suppose this can only be explained if `""` has a constructor that is not `String`, even though you would expect it.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen - because `""` is a string literal, not an instance of the `String` object. Notice how `typeof (new String());` returns "object", whereas `typeof ""` returns "string".

Comment: Ah I get it. `String` is not a "string" then? :D It's just a native object that act's like it's a string (syntactic sugar and all that).

Comment: yah, a string literal is a primitive object.  It's easy to confuse typeof "string" with the global object called String, but they're not the same.  I'm suggesting that the console.dir code probably just does an instanceof Object check on the data and if true, does a for-in loop.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen - It may not be the most exciting of reads (although it is very, very helpful when you're trying to understand the intricacies of JavaScript), but the ECMAScript spec should help clear things up: http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.16

Comment: I would like add that `typeof []` is `"object"` and `[] instanceof Array` is `true`. This doesn't seem very consistent. Could anyone explain why? All this doesn't seem very necessary.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen - I'll send you to the spec again for that one :) http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.4

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript the global String object has methods predefined in the language.  Actual string literals inherit the methods of the global String object, but otherwise have no properties except "length".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: Hum. So why isn't `''.length` printed?

Comment: I have never used console.dir.  I have always used console.log.  `''.length === 0`

Comment: not exactly.  Keep reading further down about the difference between string literals and objects

Comment: console.log expects an object literal or an array opposed to console.log that prints either a reference or a value.  The objective of console.dir is to provide access and visibility to children from a parent container.  http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.dir.28object.29