# Why are methods of String.prototype available to string literals?

Tags: javascript

This question has come out of [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569188/why-does-console-dir-print-no-properties/), which concerns the behaviour of `console.dir` with string literals. In particular, see the comments on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569188/why-does-console-dir-print-no-properties/8569235#8569235).

As we all know, `String` objects in JavaScript have a number of methods. Those methods are defined on the `String.prototype` object. `String.prototype.toUpperCase` for example. We can therefore do things like this:

```
var s = new String("hello"),
    s2 = s.toUpperCase();      //toUpperCase is a method on String.prototype
```

However, we can also do this:

```
var s = "hello",               //s is a string literal, not an instance of String
    s2 = s.toUpperCase();
```

Clearly, the JavaScript interpreter is doing some form of conversion/cast when you call a method of `String.prototype` on a string literal. However, I can't find any reference to this in the [spec](http://es5.github.com/).

It makes sense, because otherwise you'd have to explicity cast every string literal to a `String` object before you could use any of the methods, and that would be quite annoying.

So my question is, where is this functionality described, and am I right in assuming the literal value is temporarily cast to an instance of `String`? Am I over-thinking this and missing something obvious?

Comment: Btw the `new String( value )` notation is 100% useless... don't use it.

Comment: I know it is. The question is why. Where is this described in the spec?

Comment: A string literal is a string object: `typeof "hello" === "string"` returns true.  Does that get at the issue?

Comment: @bbg - That doesn't show it's a `String` object: `typeof (new String("hello")) === "object"`

Comment: @bbg A string literal evaluates to a primitive String value, not an Object value. Therefore, string literals are not objects.

Comment: Section on the String constructor: http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.4.4

Comment: @missingno - The sections on the `String` constructor, `String` object and `string` type were my first ports of call, but they don't clear anything up. See the accepted answer for the section of the spec that explains this behaviour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's defined here:

> The following [[Get]] internal method is used by GetValue when V is a
>   property reference with a primitive base value. It is called using
>   base as its this value and with property P as its argument. The
>   following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let O be ToObject(base).
> 2. Let desc be the result of calling the [[GetProperty]] internal method of O with property name P.
> 3. If desc is undefined, return undefined.
> 4. If IsDataDescriptor(desc) is true, return desc.[[Value]].
> 5. Otherwise, IsAccessorDescriptor(desc) must be true so, let getter be desc.[[Get]].
> 6. If getter is undefined, return undefined.
> 7. Return the result calling the [[Call]] internal method of getter providing base as the this value and providing no arguments.
>
> NOTE The object that may be created in step 1 is not accessible
>   outside of the above method. An implementation might choose to avoid
>   the actual creation of the object. The only situation where such an
>   actual property access that uses this internal method can have visible
>   effect is when it invokes an accessor function.

**Source:** http://es5.github.com/#x8.7.1

The primitive string value is coerced to an object in step 1.

---

**Example 1**

```
var str = 'some string';
str = str.toUpperCase();
```

Here, the expression `str.toUpperCase` is evaluated according to the semantics defined in [11.2.1 Property Accessors](http://es5.github.com/x11.html#x11.2.1):

1. The identifier `str` is evaluated according to identifier resolution (see [10.2.2.1 GetIdentifierReference](http://es5.github.com/x10.html#x10.2.2.1)). The result is a reference whose base value is the environment record of the current lexical environment, and whose referenced name is `"str"`. This reference is the *baseReference*.
2. The *baseValue* is determined by executing [`GetValue(baseReference)`](http://es5.github.com/x8.html#x8.7.1). Since *baseReference* is not a property reference (its base value is not an object or a primitive value, but an environment record), the [`GetBindingValue()`](http://es5.github.com/x10.html#x10.2.1.1.4) method is called in order to retrieve the value of the reference. This method returns the value of the local variable `str`, i.e. the primitive String value `'some string'`. This value is the *baseValue*.
3. The *propertyNameValue* evaluates to the primitive String value `'toUpperCase'`. (I've shortened this process a bit for the sake of simplicity.)
4. A new reference is created whose base value is *baseValue* and whose referenced name is *propertyNameValue*.

So, there are two references involved in this process:

- `str` (base value: the environment record, referenced name: `'str'`)
- `str.toUpperCase` (base value: `'some string'`, referenced name: `'toUpperCase'`)

Finally, the invocation operator `()` is executed on the latter reference. The value of that reference is determined according to the semantics defined at the top of this answer.

**Example 2**

```
var str = 'some string'.toUpperCase();
```

Here, the expression `'some string'.toUpperCase` is evaluated according to the same "Property Accessor" semantics as in example 1:

1. The string literal `'some string'` obviously evaluates to the primitive String value `'some string'`. This is the *baseReference*. (Don't let the name confuse you - this is a string value, not a reference.)
2. The *baseValue* is determined by executing `GetValue(baseReference)`. Since *baseReference* is not a reference, the method simply returns the argument value, i.e. *baseValue* = *baseReference*.

As you can see, just like in example 1, *baseValue* is the primitive String value `'some string'`. The steps 3 and 4 are equivalent to the steps 3 and 4 in example 1.

So, both the identifier reference `str` and the string literal `'some string'` evaluate to the same value - the primitive String value `'some string'` - and that value is used as the *baseValue* for the new reference which is then invoked with `()`. And since this reference has a primitive base value, the semantics defined at the beginning of my answer apply.

Comment: I read that as well, but how is a string literal related to a reference? What is a reference, or to be more precise, what is a resolved name binding?

Comment: `+1` - I was looking for that!

Comment: @Felix In this code - `var s = 'some string';`, and then `s.toUpperCase()` - the `s` is an identifier. [Identifiers evaluate to references.](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.2) In this case, `s` is a reference which base is a primitive value.

Comment: Ah, it all makes perfect sense :) I agree with Felix, very good job! Thanks again.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - How does a string literal evaluate to a Reference? In other words, why can we do `"hello".toUpperCase();`, without first creating a reference by assigning the literal to a variable (an identifier)?

Comment: @JamesAllardice Thanks for pointing out this case. I did some additional research and updated my answer.

Comment: @FelixKling I made a mistake in my comment above. The identifier `s` evaluates to a reference, but the base value of that reference is not the primitive string `'some string'`, but the environment record of the current lexical environment. This `s.toUpperCase` evaluates to a second reference and the base value of *this* reference is the primitive string value...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Wow, thanks for such a comprehensive answer! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what it's doing.

Javascript `boxes` primitive types as needed.

Here's some more information:

http://princepthomas.blogspot.com/2011/07/auto-boxing-javascript-primitive-types.html

Comment: That's as I assumed, but I still can't find it in the ECMAScript spec. Do you know if/where this behaviour is described in there?

Answer (score 2):

Per [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) literals are converted to objects:

> String literals (denoted by double or single quotes) and strings
>   returned from String calls in a non-constructor context (i.e., without
>   using the new keyword) are primitive strings. JavaScript automatically
>   converts primitives and String objects, so that it's possible to use
>   String object methods for primitive strings.

Comment: That's as I assumed, but I still can't find it in the ECMAScript spec. Do you know if/where this behaviour is described in there?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right. There is something called autoboxing (wrapping primitives in objects) http://princepthomas.blogspot.com/2011/07/auto-boxing-javascript-primitive-types.html

---

edit: sory for duplication of Mike Christensen link - I did not notice it.