# JavaScript and String as primitive value

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript a String is a primitive value.
But is also a String object...
A primitive value is a value put directly into a variable.

So my question is:

```
var d = "foo";
```

does d contain directly foo or a reference to a string object like other languages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand it correctly, `d` will contain the string literal "foo", and not a reference to an object. However, the JavaScript engine will effectively cast the literal to an instance of `String` when necessary, which is why you can call methods of `String.prototype` on string literals:

```
"some string".toUpperCase(); //Method of String.prototype
```

The following snippet from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) may help to explain it further (emphasis added):

> **String literals** (denoted by double or single quotes) and strings
>   returned from String calls in a non-constructor context (i.e., without
>   using the new keyword) **are primitive strings**. JavaScript automatically
>   converts primitives and String objects, so that it's possible to use
>   String object methods for primitive strings. In contexts where a
>   method is to be invoked on a primitive string or a property lookup
>   occurs, JavaScript will automatically wrap the string primitive and
>   call the method or perform the property lookup.

This is all explained in detail in the [specification](http://es5.github.com/), but it's not exactly easy reading. I asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581874/why-are-methods-of-string-prototype-available-to-string-literals) recently (about  why it is possible to do the above), so it might be worth reading the (very) detailed answer.

Answer (score 4):

if you define

```
var d = "foo";
```

than `d` contains directly `foo`
but, if you define

```
var S = new String("foo");
```

then `S` is an `Object`

Example:

```
var s1 = "1";
var s2 = "1";
s1 == s2 -> true
var S1 = new String("2");
var S2 = new String("2");
S1 == S2 -> false
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that every variable in Javascript actually represents an Object. Even a function is an Object.

Comment: Not necessarily. Some types a primitive (literal) types and get passed by value. Other objects (even functions, yes) are reference types...

Answer (score 1):

I found two useful articles detailing this, located [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch04_04.htm) and [here](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass). Seems like primitive types in JavaScript are passed by VALUE (i.e. when you pass if to a function it gets "sandboxed" within the function and the original variable's value won't change), while reference types are passed, you guessed it, by REFERENCE and passing it through to a function will change the original variable.

Primitive types in JavaScript are text (string), numeric (float / int), boolean and NULL (and the dreaded "undefined" type). Any custom objects, functions or standard arrays are considered reference types. I haven't researched the Date type though, but I'm sure it will fall into the primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

Found [**this**](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Variables_and_Types) page about javascript variables, seems that:

> Primitive type for javascript are booleans, numbers and text.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are no primitives in Javascript, in the Java sense at least - everything is an object of some kind.
So yes it is a reference to an object - if you extend the String object, `d` would have that extension.

If you mean primitives as in those types provided by the language, you've got a few, boolean, numbers, strings and dates are all defined by the language.