# JavaScript parentheses converts primitive type to object

Tags: javascript

If numbers are primitive types, why I can do:

```
> (12345).toString()
"12345"
```

Is the parenthesis converting the primitive type to a `Number`?

Comment: I asked a [somewhat related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581874/why-are-methods-of-string-prototype-available-to-string-literals) a while ago (about why it's possible to call string methods on a string literals). The answers may be of interest to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't number literals have access to Number methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046342/why-dont-number-literals-have-access-to-number-methods)

Comment: Whenever you try to use methods on a primitive JavaScript silently converts the primitive to an object with the same value and calls it for you. This is expensive. Hence if you want to use a value as an object it's generally a good idea to manually create an object rather than have JavaScript create a new object for you every time you call a method on a primitive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the parentheses are just letting the parser understand that the `.` is not a decimal point.

`12345 .toString()` will also work.

Primitive numbers implicitly converted to Numbers whenever you access their properties, but the objects are temporary and immediately lost. For example:

```
var foo = 5;

foo.bar = "something";

console.log(foo.bar); // undefined
```

Same goes for strings and booleans.

Comment: Yeah, it's always bothered me that you can terminate a number with a decimal... I've never understood that.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, `1 .toString()` works as well.

```
>>> typeof(Number(1)) === typeof(1)
true
>>> var a=1; a.toString()
"1"
```

It's the parser: 1.x expects x to be a digit.

```
>>> 1.toString()
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
[Break On This Error]
```

You can find further explanation [here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/)

> If primitives have no properties, why does "abc".length return a
>   value?
>
> Because JavaScript will readily coerce between primitives and objects. In this case the string value is coerced to a string object
>   in order to access the property length. The string object is only used
>   for a fraction of second after which it is sacrificed to the Gods of
>   garbage collection – but in the spirit of the TV discovery shows, we
>   will trap the elusive creature and preserve it for further analysis…