# JavaScript null-safe property access with "|| 0"

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I came across a clever null-safe property access trick in JavaScript while reading [this solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-binary-trees/discuss/104325/A-few-lines-of-JavaScript) to a tree-parsing problem on leetcode. It uses the OR operater (`||`) to specify default values. But in this case, it also avoids throwing an exception due to accessing a property of a primitive:

```
(MaybeObject || 0).prop
```

This evaluates to `undefined`, but I don't understand why, because the error should still arise, due to the order of evaluation:

1. Evaluate `MaybeObject`, let's say it's `undefined` (a false value).
2. Evaluate the second operand of `||`, here it's `0` (another a falsy value).
3. `false || false` evaluates to `false`.
4. Access the `prop` property of the result of the previous computation (`false`).

How is it that JavaScript does not throw an error when trying to access a non-existent property of `false`?

My first intuition was that maybe the number `0` was converted to the String `'false'`, but the following expression also evaluates to `undefined`:

```
(undefined || 0).length    // => undefined, not a String of length 5
```

Can you help me shed some light on this?

Comment: Your assumption in #3 is incorrect. `false || 0` evaluates to `0`, not `false` - therefore `(0).prop` is undefined

Comment: More relevant questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean basically `||` will return either the first truthy value or the last value. It doesn't convert into a boolean.

Comment: ((false).prop) returns undefined in chrome dev tools console...... curiouser and curiouser.... ( removing any logical operators complications from your main question)

Comment: Logical operatos don't always return boolean value. *"&& and || operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they will return a non-Boolean value"* (Even if it did, it wouldn't make a difference in your case. `(undefined || false).prop` returns `undefined`

Comment: might be because booleans can be objects as well as primitives (eg new Boolean(false) ) and it may be interpreted as an object if a property requested and then it's not there so "undefined".....

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10225638/4779501 ( lots of similar but no authoritative refs found so far )